# Twig - Iterating over Form fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm facing a problem trying to iterate over all form elements in a Twig form theme. Actually I used this to iterate over them:

```
{% for child in form.parent.children %}
```

I didn't found it in documentation, I just dumped form variable and found the fields on that path. This actually works well with all forms except when the form itself has a parameter called *children*. I don't know if it's a bug because if you just dump `form` object the structure is the same in both cases:

[image]

But if you try to access `form.parent.children` when it has a `children` parameter inside you won't get that array rather directly the result of `"children"`:

[image]

As you can see in this case `form.parent.children` refers directly to form's children element (same identifier #1592). Still if you try to get `form.parent.children.parent.children` you will get again `children` element so basically using this way is not possible to iterate over form fields if form contains a parameter called `children`.

Is it a bug or am I missing something? Maybe there's another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a name collision related to [the way Twig accesses each attribute for convenience](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) and because `FormView` is declared as `\ArrayAccess` [it has priority over object's properties](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/fd98722d15996561f598f9181dbcef8432e9ff85/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L1439-L1447). By the way, the same would happen with `parent` and `vars` properties, but let's focus on the solution now rather than on the problem.

As it is a Twig's issue the solution should be targeted on this direction. A workaround could be [create a custom function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) that obtains the property of the `FormView` correctly:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new TwigFunction('formview_prop', array($this, 'getFormViewProperty')),
    );
}

public function getFormViewProperty(FormView $formView, string $prop)
{
    // parent, children or vars
    return $formView->{$prop};
}
```

So, when using this function you can access to the view's properties rather than form's fields (if there is a name collision):

```
{% for child in formview_prop(form, 'parent') %}
```

Then, it will iterate over all field elements (children) of the parent view. However, I'd prefer be explicit by creating three functions `formview_parent`, `formview_children` and `formview_vars` instead and don't pass the second parameter.

---

In this sense, you might need verify also whether the form has a parent view or not, so since [Symfony 2.7.39, 2.8.32, 3.3.14, 3.4.1, 4.0.1 was introduced](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25236) (as bugfix) a new Twig's test function named `rootform` that avoid this kind of collision, especially for `parent` property:

```
{% if form is rootform %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for references you linked.

Comment: I realy like it, I needed this function, I worked on a task, where I create form dynamically, and didnt know how to retrieve each form field from form children